# Yii2 submit data with link

Tags: php, submit, yii2

I'm writing simple shopping app  and I have some issues with the add to cart link

I'm passing al the same parameter that were on Yii's default Crud form via get and i want to save them in database. Sad thing is when I tried to simply get 'post' to 'get' like this: its not working

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->get()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }
```

I think I am missing something very simple but I'm rather new to this so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh well i fixed that :D

```
  public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Koszyk();
        $model->setAttributes($_GET);

        if ($model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
        else {
            $m =$_GET;
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,'param'=>$m
            ]);
        }
    }
```